# Como pegar o Header de um response com Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, front-end

Como faço para pegar um Header de uma resposta com Angular 2+? No meu caso, estou usando a versão 6.

Eu gostaria pegar esse dado de authorization para ser armazenado no LocalSession do Browser.

[image: Response Header]

Estou usando o seguinte método para realizar o request:

```
public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.url, { username: email, password: password })
        .do(user => {
            this.user = user;

        });
}
```

Na classe do meu componente, tentei resgatar através do Método HttpHeaderResponse, mas sem sucesso!

```
public login(): void {
    this.signinService.login(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password
    ).subscribe(
        (user: User) => {
            this.notificationService.notify(`Usuário logado com sucesso`);
            let header: HttpHeaderResponse = new HttpHeaderResponse();
            console.log(header);
            localStorage.setItem('token', 'Aqui vai o Token');
        },
        (response: HttpErrorResponse) => this.notificationService.notify(response.error.message),
        () => {
            this.router.navigate([atob(this.navigateTo)]);
        });
}
```

Agradeço a colaboração da comunidade!

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código que você utiliza pra fazer a requisição

Comment: Adicionado Pedro! Obrigado pela Dica!

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
  public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
      return this.http
                 .post<User>(this.url, { username: email, password: password })
                  .pipe(
                    tap( resp => {
                      const token = resp.headers.get('X-Access-Token');
                      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                      this.user = user;
                    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ter acesso aos cabeçalhos e outras propriedades da resposta, precisamos passar uma opção para o método `post` com o valor `{ observe: 'response' }`.

Esta solução funciona para o Angular 6, usado pelo autor da pergunta, e também para as versão mais recentes como a 16.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class SigninService {
  private readonly url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly doc: Document,
    private readonly http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http
      .post<User>(this.url, { username, password }, { observe: "response" })
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => {
          const header = res.headers.get("authorization");
          const token = header.substring(7);
          this.doc.defaultView.localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        }),
        map((res) => res.body)
      );
  }
}
```

Note que usei o operador `tap` para extrair o cabeçalho desejado e salvar no `localStorage` e depois o `map` para passar pra frente apenas o corpo da requisição que é o que interessa para quem invoca o método `signin`.

Também preferi injetar o `Document` e acessar o `localStorage` através dele, pois assim evitamos problemas quando renderizando no lado do servidor.